# Can not connect pentaho Data integration client with Hbase under hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hbase, pentaho, socket-timeout-exception

I'm trying de load data from local pentaho data ingration client to a an Hbase server (over hadoop) but each time I get a SocketTimeoutException error.
you find below the entire error message I get.
Can anybody help me to solve this issue.
thanks in advance.

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=36, exceptions:
Wed Apr 13 16:38:25 WEST 2016, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=75228: row 'pentaho_mappings,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=localhost,16020,1460561069506, seqNum=0
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.throwEnrichedException(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:270)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:203)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:294)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:269)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:141)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:136)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:886)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.fullScan(MetaTableAccessor.java:601)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:365)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:310)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:320)
at org.pentaho.hbase.shim.common.CommonHBaseConnection.tableExists(CommonHBaseConnection.java:182)
at org.pentaho.hbase.shim.cdh54.HBaseConnectionImpl.access$801(HBaseConnectionImpl.java:32)
at org.pentaho.hbase.shim.cdh54.HBaseConnectionImpl$9.call(HBaseConnectionImpl.java:172)
at org.pentaho.hbase.shim.cdh54.HBaseConnectionImpl$9.call(HBaseConnectionImpl.java:168)
at org.pentaho.hbase.shim.cdh54.HBaseConnectionImpl.doWithContextClassLoader(HBaseConnectionImpl.java:63)
at org.pentaho.hbase.shim.cdh54.HBaseConnectionImpl.tableExists(HBaseConnectionImpl.java:168)
at org.pentaho.hbase.mapping.MappingAdmin.getMappedTables(MappingAdmin.java:557)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.hbaseoutput.HBaseOutputDialog.setupMappedTableNames(HBaseOutputDialog.java:796)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.hbaseoutput.HBaseOutputDialog.access$900(HBaseOutputDialog.java:82)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.hbaseoutput.HBaseOutputDialog$7.widgetSelected(HBaseOutputDialog.java:383)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.hbaseoutput.HBaseOutputDialog.open(HBaseOutputDialog.java:587)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonStepsDelegate.editStep(SpoonStepsDelegate.java:124)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.editStep(Spoon.java:8773)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.editStep(TransGraph.java:3061)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.mouseDoubleClick(TransGraph.java:747)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1328)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:8000)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9251)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:663)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=75228: row 'pentaho_mappings,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=localhost,16020,1460561069506, seqNum=0
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:159)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultBoundedCompletionService$QueueingFuture.run(ResultBoundedCompletionService.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:404)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:710)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:881)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:850)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1174)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:216)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:300)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:31751)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.openScanner(ScannerCallable.java:337)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:192)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:62)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:316)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:290)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:126)
... 4 more
```

Comment: Hi All, I'm still stuck on this. Can anybody help please ? Thanks

Comment: is this a core Bug or I'm the only one who got this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this property value 'hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period' set to 10 mins in hbase-default.xml to get rid of hbase exceptions.